# Balls of two colours are arranged on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

This problem came up as part of the solution to a physics problem.

Suppose that you have $N$ balls arranged in a circle, and each ball is either red or blue. We say that two neighbouring balls are in agreement if they're of the same colour (both red or both blue), while they are in disagreement if they're of different colours.

Now let's define the *index* of a certain arrangement of red and blue balls as the number of agreements minus the number of disagreements, i.e.
$$\mathrm{index} = \# \mathrm{agreements} - \# \mathrm{disagreements}$$
Is there a way of counting how many different arrangements of $N$ red/blue balls have the same index?

My thoughts: it's definitely possible to have index $N$ (with $N$ agreements an $0$ disagreements). Then I believe that the only other allowed values for the index are of the form $N-4k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This is because if we flip one colour, then either we have the same number of agreements/disagreements, or we have two more, say, disagreements and two fewer agreements, reducing the index by $4$ (or viceversa).

I have tried experimenting for small values of $N$, but I can't find a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an index of $N-4k$, there have to be $2k$ changes of colour as you go around the circle. So you are choosing $2k$ positions from a possible $N$, with the additional freedom of choosing the colour of the first position. This gives the number of arrangements with an index of $N-4k$ as simply
$$2\cdot {N\choose{2k}}$$

Comment: You need to multiply with $2$ since we can flip the colors and still have the same index

Comment: The $N$ thingss from which you choose the set of $2k$ are the gaps between the balls rather than the balls themselves (or at least I found it easier to think about it that way). Choosing the color of the first ball is equivalent "flipping the colors of all the balls" so no further factor of $2$ is needed.

Comment: Ah yes, I see! I should have thought about that! Thank you